# Reference map in locals in terraform file

Tags: terraform

In a tvfars file I have this:

```
locals {
    common = {
        "my key" = "value"
    }
}
```

because I want to use the map in multiple places in that file. I read the terraform docs about variables and I cannot find the correct syntax. I tried the following (var1 and 2 are both declared as maps):

1. With

   ```
   var1 = "${local.common}"
   var2 = "${local.common}"
   ```

   I get

   ```
   variable "var1" should be type map, got string
   ```
2. With

   ```
   var1 = locals.common
   var2 = locals.common
   ```

   I get

   ```
   invalid value "myfile.auto.tfvars" for flag -var-file-default: Error parsing myfile.auto.tfvars: At 18:15: Unknown token: 18:15 IDENT locals.common
   ```
3. With

   ```
   var1 = {"${local.common}"}
   var2 = {"${local.common}"}
   ```

   which fails without an error message but a print of terraform help and terraform exits.

I verified that everything works fine if I copy/paste the map multiple times:

```
var1 = {
     "my key" = "value"
}
var2 = {
     "my key" = "value"
}
```

Anyone know correct syntax?

Answer (score 4):

`local` blocks,interpolations and expressions that are not constants cannot be used in `terraform.tfvars` file.

See [github-issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17229) for further dicussion

The way around is to define the variable only once in `terraform.tfvars` and make the duplicate variables local in the terraform module file.

## Example:

*variable.tf*

`variable var1 {
  type = "map"
}`

*terraform.tfvars*

`var1= {
        "key1" = "value1",
        "key2" = "value2"
}`

*module.tf*

```
 locals {  
    var2="${var.var1}"  
 }  

 output show_var2 {
    value = "${local.var2}"
 }
```

Comment: This shows that I cannot use locals in tfvars, but once that is fixed, a missing piece is what the syntax would be for map. Any chance you could expand your answer to include that? I think you just need to identify the contents of the tfvars file and the variables.tf where the map would be declared.

Comment: I doubt this will work because var2 is a map too yet you are assigning a string to it. Also would it not be a lot simpler to declare common in variable.tf and give it a value in the tfvars, and define var1 and var2 in module.tf to be ${var.common}?

Comment: @Oliver not sure what you mean by "var2 is map .... assigning a string"? var1 can be assigned to var2 .i.e a map variable can be assigned to another variable in  local block .   If you want  an additional `common`  yeah sure but it has more to do with individual preference & style .